# How to structure data in elasticsearch for hourly visitors

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm struggling with how to structure my data in elasticsearch. I have one number per hour.

So it will be something like this:

```
2018-01-01T03:00:00 - 280
```

That is to say, 280 visitors for 3am. I'm confused about how to put this all into elasticsearch. Should it all be within one index, and one document as one long file?

This is going to be put on a graph in Kibana if that is any help.

Comment: Can you mention the type of graph you will be making and what will the fields on both the axes?

Comment: It would be visits on the Y axis and Time on the X axis. Thank you for the reply @Raj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a single index with two fields: `date` & `count`.
Let the document type be `_doc`.

To create an index and put a document in it with `_id` as 1:

```
PUT test/_doc/1
{
  "date":"2018-01-01T03:00:00",
  "count": 280
}
```

You can repeat this to put all the data you want to add.
For example, if the data is something like:

`[
          {
            "_index" : "test",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "1",
            "_score" : 1.0,
            "_source" : {
              "date" : "2018-01-01T03:00:00",
              "count" : 280
            }
          },
          {
            "_index" : "test",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "2",
            "_score" : 1.0,
            "_source" : {
              "date" : "2018-02-01T03:00:00",
              "count" : 1312
            }
          },
          {
            "_index" : "test",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "3",
            "_score" : 1.0,
            "_source" : {
              "date" : "2018-03-01T03:00:00",
              "count" : 124
            }
          },
          {
            "_index" : "test",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "5",
            "_score" : 1.0,
            "_source" : {
              "date" : "2018-05-01T03:00:00",
              "count" : 34
            }
          },
          {
            "_index" : "test",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "7",
            "_score" : 1.0,
            "_source" : {
              "date" : "2018-01-01T03:00:00",
              "count" : 280
            }
          }
        ]`

Then you can visualize the count per month for example as :

[image]

Add the bucket as:

[image]

PS: elasticsearch has [`date_detection`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/dynamic-field-mapping.html#date-detection) enabled by default so you date string will automatically be persisted as a date type.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can I check, are you saying if I have 50 different entries, like 50 hours of data, it all goes in one doc in one index?

Comment: All the data in one single index with a single mapping type(`_doc`) as 50 different documents. PS: mapping type is deprecated [https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html]